# Woocommerce: Custom product order for each product category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to order my products in a specific order in each product category.

I have many products with multiple categories, but some should appear "higher up" in some categories than others.

I, therefore, need a way to arrange the products like I want to for each product.

I've already seen this thread:
[Wordpress Woocommerce sort products differently per category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35777971/wordpress-woocommerce-sort-products-differently-per-category)
but it only allowed to use the default "sort by price" and "sort by popularity" and so on. I need to arrange the products myself for each category.

Does someone know an existing plugin or something else to do this with?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide more information, e.g. Are you using php as in the question you linked?

Comment: I'm not really a PHP-Developer, but if anyone has finished code i would be happy to use it. But the ideal would be a plugin if someone knew any.

Comment: So you're asking for us to write code/find plugins for you? That's considered to be off-topic.